# Can I make a member function only accessible through another class member function?

Tags: c++, methods, scope, friend

As far as my knowledge goes, a friend function will give the function free access to the entire class. Can I scope this friend function by only letting it access a single member function?

For example:

```
class ResourceCache {
    Resource* Create(ResourceDesc) {
        ...
        return ResourceDesc.Create();
    }
}

class ResourceDesc {
    ...
    Resource* Create();
}
```

In this example, I want `ResourceCache::Create` to only have access to `ResourceDesc::Create`, but not to all of `ResourceDesc`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8):

C++ doesn't give you access control this fine-grained.  Don't worry too much about getting the access control precisely right, it's all code you or your collaborators have written anyway, what bad thing are you afraid might happen?

Comment: Was just thinking on organization and cleanness..Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Honestly don't see how it contributes to organization or cleanliness. But okay!

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't allow that.

My immediate thought would be that if you want to do this, it's at least a possible indication that your `ResourceDesc` (and possibly `ResourceCache` as well) may be on the large side and may do more than one class really should.